# Populate second dropdown box with same values as the first using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown boxes that are specifically used for users to select year intervals. I currently have both dropdown boxes being populated by using a "select distinct year from TABLE" query to my database. However, I would like to just populate the second dropdown box with the same year the user selected and include the years after the first selection. For example, if the user selects '1995' in the first dropdown menu, I would like the second dropdown box to contain any years from '1995' to present. That would prevent the user from selecting '1995' in the first box and '1990' in the second (which would be an incorrect time interval). I really have no clue how to go about this. I am not very familiar with javascript. Is that what I need to use? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YNuna/1/

HTML:

```
<select id=first>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2013</option>
</select>

<select id=second> 
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#first").change(function(){
    var val = $("#first option:selected").html();
    $("#second").html("");
    var d = new Date();
     var n = d.getFullYear();

    for (i=val; i<=n;i++){
        $("#second").append("<option>" + i + "</option>");
    }
});´
```

You need to include jquery aswell

**EDIT:**

But it can be done without jquery but then you need to modify the code a bit...

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you. Just need basic calculation for maintaining requirment

```
http://www.creativecg.com/addremove-options-from-a-select-box-with-jquery/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cMhzj/

Using my solution, you need to fill only the 1st `dropdown` (you can fill both, both not required). Then when you select a year, the 2nd one is populated with all the years from the year selected.